# Two horizontal lines beetween an ImageButton

Tags: android

I want to to set two line from the left and right corner of my activity to my imageView [like on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVLmY.png). Activity below was drawed using static dp. But when I'm swithing on device with smaller screen, lines uppears under my image. How to do it stable?

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/delimiter"
    android:layout_width="181dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#FFCFD8DC"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/delimiter2"
    android:layout_width="182dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#FFCFD8DC"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_up" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple if you use `RelativeLayout` as it as `toLeftOf` & `toRightOf`. Wrap your both views and ImageButton inside Relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_marginTop="16dp" 
  android:layout_centerVertical="true">

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/button_up"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:src="@drawable/arrow_up" />
<View
  android:background="#FFCFD8DC"
  android:layout_height="1dp" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button_up"/>

 <View 
   android:background="#FFCFD8DC"
   android:layout_height="1dp"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_up"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wrap_content instead of static dp.

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

use ConstraintLayout as parent and change your xml file like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/delimiter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button_up"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="#FFCFD8DC"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/delimiter2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button_up"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="#FFCFD8DC"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_up" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```